# Allow HTML5 Video to enter fullscreen in webview

Tags: cocoa, webview, fullscreen

I have an extremely simple test app setup. All it does is show a webview and load a Youtube Video page. The page loads and video plays all fine, however clicking on the full screen link has no effect. (see screenshot below). I checked that if the video is playing using Flash player fullscreen works just fine, but HTML5 fullscreen does not work. Is there some kind of delegate calls or other workarounds that can enable HTML5 fullscreen video in Webview?

[image]

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate()
@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *webview;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSString *url = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/VCERs0v1OoI?html5=1";
    self.webview.mainFrameURL = url;
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: I've exactly the same problem, did you figure out how to solve it?